# how to change the color of a button of over touch in android

Tags: android, touch

when I click of touch the button I want to change its color dark blue,while my activity will not come.

How can I do this.

Please help me.

Comment: you mean,when you select the button?

Comment: Ni I mean,when I click or touch the button then my button color will be chnage

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color of button using this code

```
  Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it with XML:

[File: login_button.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_down"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_up" />
</selector>
```

And in your layout XML File:

```
    <de.pkeidel.testapp.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/home_login"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button" />
```